# How to remove the special character from any length of the string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sample Data

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | Name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | $John     |
|  2 | $Carol    |
|  3 | $Mike     | 
|  4 | $Sam      |
|  5 | $David$Mohan$ |
   6 | $David$
   7 | $David$Mohan$
|  8 | Robert$Ram$   |  
|  9 | Maxwell$ |
+----+-----------+
```

I need to remove the only $ first character

Need output  :

```
+----+-----------+
| Id | Name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | John     |
|  2 | Carol    |
|  3 | Mike     | 
|  4 | Sam      |
|  5 | David$Mohan |
   6 | David
   7 | David$Mohan
|  8 | Robert$Ram   |  
|  9 | Maxwell |
+----+-----------+



   Select REPLACE(col,'$','') from Tbl 
select regexp_replace(name, '^$', '') name from mytable
```

I have tried with Replace and Substring but still missing the point . 
Can anyone suggest me .

Comment: How come `Robert$Ram$` becomes `Robert$Ram` if you remove the first `$`?

Comment: Use `POSITION(substring IN string)` to find first $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only looking for starting $, you can use this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a601fc06cd3aa414a6ba4772bf71b26f)

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(D,1) = '$' THEN RIGHT(D, LENGTH(D)-1) 
    ELSE D 
END STR,
IF(LEFT(D,1) = '$', RIGHT(D, LENGTH(D)-1), D) STR2
-- you can use any of the above option
FROM 
(
    select '$David$Mohan$' D UNION ALL
    select 'Da$Mo$'
)A
```

Comment: Long `CASE ... END` can be shortened to `IF(LEFT(D,1) = '$', RIGHT(D, LENGTH(D)-1), D)`

Comment: @Stalinko thanks. Thats a nice option. I have added the option in script

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
select 
id,
case when SUBSTR(Name, 1,1)='$' and SUBSTR(Name,-1,1)='$' then substr(Name,2,(length(Name)-2))          
when SUBSTR(Name, 1,1)='$' then substr(Name,2)          
else Name
end
from Tbl
```

Comment: Will remove the first character, $ or other. Will not remove the first $ if it is found later in the string.

Comment: Will still not remove $ character found later in string. E.g. `Maxwell$` should become `Maxwell`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example you should try;

```
Replace(trim(replace({col},'$',' ')), ' ','$')
```

This is turning the '$' into spaces, removing spaces at the start or end or the string, then switching back to '$'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working for me for all your test cases

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,'[^$].+[^$]') from users;
```

If case you want to replace $ with space, `David$Ang` => `David Ang`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,'[^$].+[^$]'), "[$]", " ") from users;
```